# How to wait for 2 of Promises in Promise.all to finish and then do another task

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I'm currently developing a program where I need to use Promise.all to run a few functions at the same time. But before I can continue with the task, I need ONLY 2 of the promises to finish and then run the .then(), how would I go about doing this?

Example:

```
await Promise.all([Task1(),Task2(),Task3(),Task4(),Task5()]);
```

I need it to continue the code when only (for example) Task1 and Task 4 have finished.

I have tried to experiment by using a while loop waiting for Task1 and Task2 finish by settings variables on the finish, but that. doesn't work at all.

Comment: Can it be *any* two?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's 2 specific promises, just chose randomly for the example.

Comment: Then why not pass only two functions instead of all four?

Comment: @SamH - Again, can it be *any* two (e.g., the first two that finish)? Or do you have two specifically in mind?

Comment: The mission was to run all 5 Tasks at the same time by using Promise.all (because they take time to finish, seconds) Sometimes some tasks might take longer time than others that's why I still want to continue waiting for the other promises while continuing with another task when Task1 and Task4 have finished. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @SamH - So it's **specifically** Task 1 and Task 4?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well Task1 and Task4 is just an example, but yes, Its specifically 2 Tasks I need to wait for, not random tasks, but 2 specific tasks that return specific results.

Comment: @SamH - "just an example" just makes things unclear. If you know in advance which ones it is, that's the key point to make clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a comment you seem to have said you specifically know that in advance which two are more urgent than the rest (and that in this example, it's Task1 and Task4).

Then just use `Promise.all` twice:

```
const allResults = Promise.all([
    Promise.all([Task1(), Task4()])
    .then(([result1, result4]) => {
        // Those two are done, do what you like with `result1` and `result4`...
        return [result1, result4];
    }),
    Task2(),
    Task3(),
    Task5()
])
.then(([[result1, result4], result2, result3, result5]) => {
    // All five are done now, let's put them in order
    return [result1, result2, result3, result4, result5];
})
.then(/*...*/)
.catch(/*...*/);
```

In there, I've preserved the overall 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 order in the outer chain by remapping the order in the overall `then` handler.

---

Originally, I assumed you wanted to wait until **any** two have finished, rather than a specific two. There's no built-in for that, but it's easy enough to write:

```
function enough(promises, min) {
  if (typeof min !== "number") {
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
  let counter = 0;
  const results = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let index = 0;
    for (const promise of promises) {
      let position = index++;
      promise.then(
        result => {
          results[position] = result;
          if (++counter >= min) {
            resolve(results);
          }
        },
        reject
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function enough(promises, min) {
  if (typeof min !== "number") {
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
  let counter = 0;
  const results = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let index = 0;
    for (const promise of promises) {
      let position = index++;
      promise.then(
        result => {
          results[position] = result;
          if (++counter >= min) {
            resolve(results);
          }
        },
        reject
      );
    }
  });
}

const delay = (ms, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args));
const rnd = () => Math.random() * 1000;

enough(
  [
    delay(rnd(), "a"),
    delay(rnd(), "b"),
    delay(rnd(), "c"),
    delay(rnd(), "d"),
    delay(rnd(), "e")
  ],
  2
)
.then(results => {
  console.log(results);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by constructing a new array of the randomized promises, and then wait for those only:

```
let array = [Task1(),Task2(),Task3(),Task4(),Task5()];

// Select any two promises after running the randomization logic
let promises = Promise.all[array[1], array[3]];

promises
  .then(() => {
    // Do stuff here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all()` does not run your tasks simultaneously, it only awaits all Promises to resolve before resolving the returned Promise.

Your tasks will be run as soon as you create each Promise.

If you want to wait after specific tasks, only include those tasks in `Promise.all`:

```
const tasks = [Task2(), Task3(), Task5()];
const result1 = await Promise.all([Task1(), Task4()]);
// Task1 and Task4 are done here
const result2 = await Promise.all(tasks);
// All remaining tasks are done here
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen tricks like this :
`Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(() => undefined)));`
Quite unsafe though.
Original answer : [here](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/833668073475416064)

Answer (score 0):

OK, as I understand you, you want to do something like

```
const importantOnes = [Task1(), Task2()];
const remainingOnes = [Task3(), Task4(), Task5()];
const priorityPromise = Promise.all(importantOnes);

priorityPromise.then(doPriorityStuff);
Promise.all([priorityPromise, ...remainingOnes]).then(processTheCompleteData);
```